# Home screen flashes sometimes when performing a fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

In my main activity, I have these two functions:

```kotlin
fun showSettingsFragment() {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, settingsFragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}

fun showMainMenuFragment() {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mainMenuFragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

I use call them from my the respective fragments to toggle which one shows on screen. Here is the main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is the following:

When the transaction occurs, my phone's home screen (where the apps are) randomly shows for ~1 frame about one fifth of the the time, which is mildly annoying. However, the transaction still occurs successfully and I can navigate between the two fragments.

Does anyone else experience this? Does someone know what is happening?

Comment: What theme do you use on your activity? Specifically, are you setting a null `windowBackground`?

Comment: It sounds a bit shady to me that `settingsFragment` is a field variable. If it is not initialized with `findFragmentByTag` then this can cause strangeness. See https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0 #2

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you for the feedback, I changed it to use `findFragmentByTag` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the reason. The button I use for one of the transactions is in the bottom left on my screen; when I press it too close to the corner, it triggers the currently running application menu, but only the beginning of the animation. Sorry for making you search!

Answer (score -1):

Because you use FragmentTransaction, you have to use layout fragment.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:name="[your fragment]"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly wrong - you **cannot** use FragmentTransactions if you use `<fragment>`.

Comment: But when I try, it works using ```<fragment>``` according to the case above. I'm using the action button. Then, set fragment like that function. Correct me if I'm wrong.